# Same Error and I have tried all possible fixes, Insufficient Funds gas * price + value

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, ethers.js

So, I'm constantly facing this error and there aren't much about it except what I already fathom but is not the case, see, I have sufficient balance for gas, and for the eth value to transfer; I kept it 0, but the transaction is still not broadcasting.

To the people who're thinking what I'm trying to do: I'm actually trying to send unconfirmed transactions of unavialble funds(flasg eth) through eth network(I know there are validity check that I have to bypass, which I will do later, but I'm already stuck in just only broadcasting a legitimate transaction!

```
const { ethers } = require("ethers");

async function sendTransaction() {
    const ethereumNodeUrl = 'https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/085077982f094073a03893b9e3e338ec';

    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(ethereumNodeUrl);

    const senderAddress = '0x0112fa4CB650dCa6eE0f9Bd74106EbB27C382622';
    const recipientAddress = '0xA705f5c1dEb081D329EdD2d2ED6817f161Cfd1F0';

    const privateKey = 'MY_PVT_KEY'; 

    try {
        const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);

        const tx = {
            to: recipientAddress,
            value: ethers.utils.parseEther('0'), // Set the value to 0.1 ETH (100 ether in wei)
            gasLimit: ethers.utils.hexlify(21000), // Adjust gas limit accordingly
            gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits('25', 'gwei'), // Adjust gas price accordingly
        };

        // Create and broadcast the transaction
        const txResponse = await wallet.sendTransaction(tx);
        console.log(`Transaction hash: ${txResponse.hash}`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    }
}

sendTransaction();
```

Comment: Can you share the details or stack trace of the error you are getting?